# Issues running Ubuntu 19.04 and Windows10 in dual-boot

Tags: 19.04

I actually have Windows10 pre-installed in my laptop and I am running ubuntu through vm-ware workstation .

I don't know what to do here:

When I open the terminal of Ubuntu to verify that the Ubuntu installation is successfull or not by using the code

```
echo "2da6f8b5c65b71b040c5c510311eae1798545b8ba801c9b63e9e3fd3c0457cbe *ubuntu-19.04-desktop-amd64.iso" | shasum -a 256 --check"
```

I am getting the output as:

> .iso is not located i.e no such file or directory is found .

so should i again have to download .iso file

Answer (score 1):

Checking the `.iso` file's SHA hash has to be done *before* you install Ubuntu (I.E. [in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/245775/is-there-a-built-in-checksum-utility-on-windows-7).  `shasum` will:

1. tell you whether *the download* was successful
2. **will not tell you** whether *your installation* was successful.

If Ubuntu works, **congratulations!** That's it!